# threadsafe ffi-rzmq ruby and zeromq

Tags: ruby, thread-safety, zeromq

I'm working on an app that has several different zeromq socket types talking to each other,  I have done very little threaded programming. The thing i'm currently mulling over has 2 threads, one to push and pull from a xrec socket, and another thread which passes messages to a pair socket.

I'm thinking of using a simple array to push/shift or pop the messages in a simple internal queue.  I doubt there will be much actual queuing but it seems like a good design. I suppose I could add a short circuit on a.size > max

- wondering it the below code is threadsafe?
- what I can do to test the threadsafety of the code?
- any things I should be looking out for?

... I'm most worried about the << in place modification

```
require 'thread'

m = Mutex.new
endl = false
a = []
t1 = Thread.new do
  runs = 0
  while !endl
    runs += 1
    msg = nil
    m.synchronize{msg = a.pop}
    puts "pulled -#{msg}-" if msg
    sleep(0.001)
  end
  puts "t1 exiting runs: #{runs}"
end
t2 = Thread.new do
  while !endl
    puts "endl is #{endl}"
    s = $stdin.gets
    s.chomp!
    if s == 'end'
      puts "end found... trying to exit"
      m.synchronize {endl = true}
    elsif s == 'blast'
      100.times.each_with_index  do |item,i|
        m.synchronize{a << i}
      end
    else
      m.synchronize {a << s}
      puts "ECHO: #{s}"
    end
  end
  puts "t2 exiting endl was #{endl}"
end
t1.join()
t2.join()
```

EDIT:

at this point I'm going to be using inproc and message passing to avoid use of any mutexes.  It should be fast enough, and if I need to peel a component out I can easily do it.

Comment: Ok, I guess i'm doing something wrong because I get a malloc(): memory corruption error in my code. It only happens with jruby.